# CSS/HTML/JS: what to watch out for when building website that will have a mobile layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm building a website that will need to have diff mobile layouts depending on the screen size of the device but I don't want to have to design entirely new layouts for each device. So I was wondering if there are things I need to watch out for that don't convert well into a mobile layout? Or how to set up the original to scale well to smaller devices. Thanks a lot

Comment: Google "responsive website design" and probably [read this one first](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/).

Comment: Only one stop [less framework](http://lessframework.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about media queries:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Then read about responsive layouts done with purely CSS:

http://css-tricks.com/6731-css-media-queries/

Answer (score 1):

This is basically all about styles and sometimes javascript (if you want to make responsive design)
Take a look on what CSS should be loaded for different devices and how to use

http://podlipensky.com/post/2011/08/25/What-CSS-file-to-load-for-mobile.aspx

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/return-of-the-mobile-stylesheet

And here you can read about responsive web design

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

http://thinkvitamin.com/design/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design/